# Best Windows Process Information Database

Tags: windows

Searching for information about a particular Windows process typically turns up sites (like processlibrary.com, liutilities.com, process-info.org, etc) that are less than helpful, all seem to be copies of themselves and often ... sketchy.

Does anyone have a better recommendation for researching Windows process information?

(Not the tools to discover what processes are currently running, but the resources to learn more about what they might be.)

Answer (score 3):

The best one that I have used in the past is http://answersthatwork.com/

Comment: I was kind of hoping for a more community driven site. Though not as sketchy as most, this one still reads as a big advertisement for their Ultimate Troubleshooter software.

Comment: The problem with community driven sites for this sort of thing is that they tend to not always be populated by people who know what they're talking about.  It is a bit of an advertisement, but it's pretty accurate most of the time.